# Only digits from tesseract - OCR on VB?

Tags: vb.net, ocr, tesseract, digits, emgucv

I needed an app that observed numbers in my screen and then make calculations with it, so after some days on researching the best and easiest method i found this video
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kjdu8SjEtG0) that leaded me to OCR and EMGU-Tesseract on Visual Basic 2010 express. I understanded the video and I made my own variation of the code on the description of the video.

I imported:

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.OCR
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
```

then i make this based on the original code:

```
Dim OCRz As Tesseract = New Tesseract("tessdata", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY)
Dim picStc1 As Bitmap = New Bitmap(149, 28)
Dim gfxSTK1 As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(picStc1)
Dim picNam1 As Bitmap = New Bitmap(149, 28)
Dim gfxNAM1 As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(picNam1)


Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    gfxSTK1.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Me.Location.X + Stk1.Location.X + 5, Me.Location.Y + Stk1.Location.Y + 24), New Point(0, 0), picStc1.Size)
    Stk1.Image = picStc1

    gfxNAM1.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Me.Location.X + Nome1.Location.X + 5, Me.Location.Y + Nome1.Location.Y + 24), New Point(0, 0), picNam1.Size)
    Nome1.Image = picNam1
```

And when i pressed the button i get this :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    OCRz.Recognize(New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(picStc1))
    BOXSTK1.Text = OCRz.GetText

    OCRz.Recognize(New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(picNam1))
    BoxNAME1.Text = OCRz.GetText
```

I now have the text read from the PictureBoxes (picStc1) and (picNam1) thru the OCR engine and its writen on the RichTextBoxes (BoxSTK1) and (NAME1) after i pressed the button.

The numbers on the RichTextBox (BoxSTK1) come with commas and other simbols but i just want to grab the numbers. So i found this (https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_recognize_only_digits?) but i cant implement it on the project, any help on this?

(I´m using Emgu 2.9.0.1922, dont know how to see the version of Tesseract)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This digit-based "whitelist" appears to be something you'd set when you initialize the object.
[Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609204/strange-error-when-using-tesseract-in-vb-net)

So you will need to change,

```
Dim OCRz As Tesseract = New Tesseract("tessdata", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY)
```

To something like this,

```
Dim OCRz As Tesseract = New Tesseract()
OCRz.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789")
OCRz.init("tessdata", "eng", false)
```

Comment: Hey Jimmy ty for that, u are the best, You were fast to answer and the simpler it could be and it works nicely... But i still have a problem with this... Every time the OCR found a "$" symbol it converts it to a "5" instead of ignoring.... buahhhhhhhhhhhh resolved one thing and maked another worst to resolve... Anytoughts? Did I already mention that you are the BEST :) tytyty

Comment: No problemo, I couldn't find any documentation on that issue (or on Tesseract in general?) but I know $ is easy to interpret as 5.  For a sneaky workaround(to test), you could add $ to the whitelist "$0123456789", then do a replace on the string like so, `OCRz.GetText.replace("$", "")`

Comment: Hello again my newest friend Jimmy, I´m Peter... So I get "Copy exception detail to the clipboard" when i put the `OCRz.GetText.Replace` after `OCRz.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789")` and after `OCRz.init("tessdata", "eng", false)` ..... When i put after `OCRz.Recognize(New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(picStc1))` it now it doesnt transform the symbol "$" to "5" but it appears the "$"... so I guess I tried every possible variation...

Comment: where u read "Copy exception detail to the clipboard" should be read "System.AccessViolationException was unhandled"

Comment: Update: also tried `OCRz.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "$0123456789")` then `OCRz.SetVariable("tessedit_char_blacklist", "$")` no result

Comment: GetText may not return a string, as I was assuming it did.  You can try `Convert.ToString(OCRz.GetText).Replace("$","")`  but all I'm doing is a potential workaround.

Comment: Also, have you "trained" it?  There is little to no documentation available on this control, which make it frustrating for me to utilize it.  https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3

Comment: I think we've conquered your original question and happy to help.  I would try training the library, and afterwards if that persists, we could move this to another question.

Comment: My Frieeeend!!! I you got it! We got it! Tytyty You are the best. Here goes the solution for anyone getting this problem (no need to train the tesseract). `OCRz.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", ",$0123456789")


        OCRz.Init("tessdata", "eng", False)


        OCRz.Recognize(New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(pic))
        RichTextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(OCRz.GetText).Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "")`

Answer (score 0):

Ok people, this problem is solved! Thanks to Mr.Jimmy Smith!
Now we dont need to train any tesseract. 
By converting the OCR value to a string!

First define the whitelist by using this:

```
OCRz.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", ",$0123456789")
```

Then convert the string like this and print it:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(OCRz.GetText).Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "")
```

At the end we get this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    OCRz.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", ",$0123456789")


    OCRz.Init("tessdata", "eng", False)


    OCRz.Recognize(New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(pic))
    RichTextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(OCRz.GetText).Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "")
```

I will thank Jimmy Smith again for his fast answers and really useful, mind yourselves to up vote this guy ;)

Answer (score 0):

[On fix and download](http://laptrinhvb.net/bai-viet/chuyen-de-vb-net/Su-dung-Emgu-CV-xuat-text-ra-khoi-hinh-anh-%28Extract-Text-From-Image-Use-Emgu-CV-VB-NET%29/c490e8fcb447a7eb.html):

```
Dim OCRz As Tesseract = 
 New Tesseract("tessdata", "eng",Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT)
Dim pic As Bitmap = New Bitmap(270, 100)
Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pic)
```

Comment: Format it when answering .. for help look on http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting